# Recursion Error(Jupyter Notebook/Google Colab)Repost

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This is just a repost from yesterday but I have new details to add. Take a look:

I'm creating a map that contains points that features a description of the location. I get a Recursion Error when I try to run my code. "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(10):
    lat = map_data['LATLNG'].iloc[i][0]
    long = map_data['LATLNG'].iloc[i][1]
    location=map_data['address'].iloc[i]

    if map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] > 150:
        color = 'red'
    elif map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] >= 100:
        color = 'orange'
    elif map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i] < 100:
        color = 'blue'
    
    popup_text = """
                Location: {}<br>
                Peace Disruptions : {}<br>"""
    popup_text = popup_text.format(
                               location, 
                               map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i]
                             )

    folium.Marker( location = [lat, long], popup= popup_text,icon = folium.Icon(color= color).add_to(stl_crime_street)
```

Here was the traceback call:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-e1777bcd5945> in <module>()
     17                                map_data['ValueCount'].iloc[i]
     18                                )
---> 19     folium.Marker(location = [lat, long], popup= popup_text,icon=folium.Icon(color= color)).add_to(stl_crime_street)


   69     for i in container:
     70         if _is_sized_iterable(i):
---> 71             for j in _flatten(i):
     72                 yield j
     73         else:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I don't know if the reason for this is because of my map_data code which is

```
#count the incident frenquency to each location
unique_locations = df['LATLNG'].value_counts()

PB_index = pd.DataFrame({"LATLNG" : unique_locations.index, "ValueCount":unique_locations})
PB_index.index = range(len(unique_locations))
#map_data=pd.concat([new_df['address'],PB_index], axis=1, join='inner')
map_data=pd.concat([df[['address']],PB_index], axis=1, join='inner')
map_data_head=map_data[:10]
map_data.head()
```

[image: map_data.head() Result]

and no,
this doesn't work

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500) # for example 1500
```